# Twitter API v1.1 for iOS

Tags: iphone, twitter

Where can I get the new Twitter API v1.1 for iOS SDK?

I was using the REST API v1 before, now I am getting the message on hitting the URL:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xyz

"{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. 
Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", 
"code": 68}]}
```

Comment: I know it sounds too simple but change 1 to 1.1 in the URL and see what happens.

Comment: Please make changes in URLs used for Twitter request to v1.1. That would pretty much do it as v1.0 is already closed. So migration is compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter API v1.0 is no longer supported, while changing the 1.0 to 1.1 in your call will connect you to 1.1 it will not fix your error. Twitter API v1.1 now requires apps to authenticate before viewing feeds/posting. [Version 1.1 overview](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview)